# ORA-12570: Network Session - after running 20 odd minutes

Tags: odp.net-managed

We are getting network session error.

> "ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error".

This comes after running queries 20-21 minutes. Its consistently throwing this error in all cases if I run a single query or multiple queries.

Till 20 mins it works fine and the logs show all fine. We are fetching prod log records to store it in a master csv file. The log records are in millions and it takes a lot time to fetch. It was running successfully till last month.

- I have taken latest ODP.net "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.24160419" through nuget.
- Tried with various Pooling options. Even pooling off also didn't help.

How can I solve the error . Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: "This comes after running queries 20-21 minutes"..Do you run all queries on the same connection?

Comment: No. One after one, like getting data for a month I break it in multiple queries for each day.

Comment: Ok, Could you provide the code where you communicate with the database